# find a:selected element from list using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css-selectors, jquery-selectors

I need to pick an ID tag with a selected element. I also need to consider I have nested `<ul>` with `<li>`. I will always have only one tag with element `selected="selected"`. The JQuery I have provided is not working.

### JQuery

```
 $(".SortFilterMenu li").find("a:selected").attr("id");
```

### HTML

```
 <ul class="SortFilterMenu">
            <li><a id="RecommendedSort" value="Recommended" class="sortLabelElement sortTag sortClickedEvent" selected="selected">Our Recommendation</a></li>
         //rest of code here ..
```

What am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selected attribute is intended for `<option>` elements inside a `<select>` element. jQuery's pseudo-selector `:selected` is only intended to match `<option>` elements that have this attribute.

Nevertheless, it IS possible to select other HTML elements with a `selected` attribute that has value `selected`, by doing this :

```
$(".SortFilterMenu li").find("a[selected=selected]").attr("id"));
```

---

#### A demo :

```js
alert($(".SortFilterMenu li").find("a[selected=selected]").attr("id"));
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<ul class="SortFilterMenu">
    <li><a id="RecommendedSort" value="Recommended" class="sortLabelElement sortTag sortClickedEvent" selected="selected">Our Recommendation</a></li>
    <li><a id="AnotherSort" value="AnotherOne" class="sortLabelElement sortTag sortClickedEvent">Something else</a></li>
    <li><a id="YetAnotherSort" value="YetAnotherOne" class="sortLabelElement sortTag sortClickedEvent">Something more</a></li>
</ul>
```

---

#### Note :

While `value` and `selected` are perfectly valid attributes for an `<option>` element, they [**aren't valid attributes for the `<a>` element**](https://validator.w3.org). While browsers are supposed to ignore this, it's better to use only valid attributes. For custom attributes, it means that their name should start with `data-`.

So, just rename `value` as `date-value` and `selected` as `date-selected`, and you do have valid HTML :

```js
alert($(".SortFilterMenu li").find("a[data-selected=selected]").attr("id"));
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<ul class="SortFilterMenu">
    <li><a id="RecommendedSort" data-value="Recommended" class="sortLabelElement sortTag sortClickedEvent" data-selected="selected">Our Recommendation</a></li>
    <li><a id="AnotherSort" data-value="AnotherOne" class="sortLabelElement sortTag sortClickedEvent">Something else</a></li>
    <li><a id="YetAnotherSort" data-value="YetAnotherOne" class="sortLabelElement sortTag sortClickedEvent">Something more</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

`<option>`s can be selected, `<a>`s cannot.

If you want to match invalid extendo-attributes, then you have to use an attribute selector.

```
a[selected]
```

You should use something else to indicate the state, such as a class.

Answer (score 1):

Use a class instead of attribute.

Setting an attribute only on one element of a collection is more complicated than using classes that are simple to toggle

```
<li><a id="RecommendedSort" data-value="Recommended" 
       class="sortLabelElement sortTag sortClickedEvent selected">
        Our Recommendation
    </a>
</li>
```

Then selector is

```
$(".SortFilterMenu li a.selected").attr("id");
```